# Restoring iOS 7.1 to iOS 7.0.4

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, jailbreak

I'm trying to Downgrade my iPhone 5s from iOS 7.1 to iOS 7.0.4.

I have been looking at tutorials, and found this one [Downgrading iOS 7.1 with iTunes](http://motoringcrunch.com/news/can-you-simply-downgrade-from-ios-7-1-with-itunes-alone/10012341/)

It worked up until the last step. My iPhone starts to Extract the Software, then a popup comes up saying "This device is not eligible for the requested build". After seeing this, I went to [This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHb1vdU6ReM)

I followed the steps, but it still comes up with the same error message.

Can someone please tell me how to remove this "This device is not eligible for the requested build" error message?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That was never going to work, Apple stopped signing everything under iOS 7.1. So you can't downgrade at all. Unless you have an iPhone 4 with SHSH blobs and downgrade to iOS 6.1.3.